# In python, how can I enumerate (and modify) every point in a complex object?

Tags: python

In python, how can I enumerate (and modify) every point in a complex object? I want to write some functions to perform certain "warping" operations on objects.

Will moving the points in objects be all that is required to perform changes on them, or are there other data structures or references that would need to be modified as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly edit a vertex of the active object like this:

```
bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices[0].co=Vector( (2,2,2) )
```

This requires you to be in OBJECT mode.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

# Make sure we have a mesh object
if bpy.context.active_object.type != 'MESH':
    raise ValueError('Active object not a mesh')

# save a handy pointer
obj=bpy.context.active_object
# must be in object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# loop through the verts and change some
for vert in obj.data.vertices:
     if vert.co[0] > 0.5 and vert.co[1] > 0.5:
         vert.co = Vector( (0,0,0) )
         print('Setting vertex')
```

There is some benefit to be had by using the bmesh library to access mesh data,

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

# Make sure we have a mesh object
if bpy.context.active_object.type != 'MESH':
    raise ValueError('Active object not a mesh')

# save some handy pointers
obj=bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
me = obj.data
# instanciate the bmesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# loop through the verts and change some
for vert in bm.verts:
     if vert.co[0] > 0.5 and vert.co[1] > 0.5:
         vert.co = Vector( (0,0,0) )
         print('Setting vertex')

# write the changes back to the mesh
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me) 
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Also if you're batch editing a big number of vertices, and it takes a lot of time, consider looking up numpy arrays